# Why function works when declaring variable globally but not with var

Tags: javascript, variables, parameters, global-variables, var

I would like to declare the property `soundFileName` as `var soundFileName = 'audio/60.wav';` so that `soundFileName` isn't defined globally, but when I do I get `ReferenceError: soundFileName is not defined`.

I am passing the value of `soundFileName` as a parameter to `loop(soundFileName)`, and I would think the value `'audio/60.wav'` should pass along just fine.

I suspect this has something to do with scope or nesting but I'm not sure how to resolve the issue. The code does work when I use `soundFileName = 'audio/60.wav';` without var.

What am I missing? Thanks!

EDIT: Code now working and updated!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

  <script src="js/howler.core.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

</head>

<body>

  <script src="timeprobabilities.js"></script>

  <script>
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // MASTER START ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // initiates fist call to all clocks to each will start and can then be called again

    (function masterStart() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        //// LOOP SOUNDS \\\\
        A();
      }, 0);
    }());

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // LOOPS SHARED OPTIONS ///////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    var options = {
      numberOfSounds: 0,
      maxNumberOfSounds: 4
    };

    function logNumberOfSounds() { // passing options into this before is what broke code
      options.numberOfSounds++;
      //console.log('Number of sounds is: ' + options.numberOfSounds + '########');
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // LOOP A  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    function A() {
      var optionsA = {
        playDurationMin: 0,
        playDurationMax: 60000,
        // start time minimum and maximum
        startMinA: 0,
        startMaxA: 8000,
        maxVolumeA: 1,
        //
        startMinB: 0,
        startMaxB: 30000,
        maxVolumeB: 1,
        //
        startMinC: 0,
        startMaxC: 30000,
        maxVolumeC: 1,
        //
        startMinD: 0,
        startMaxD: 30000,
        maxVolumeD: 1,
        //
        startMinE: 0,
        startMaxE: 30000,
        maxVolumeE: 1,
        //
        startMinF: 0,
        startMaxF: 30000,
        maxVolumeF: 1,
        //
        startMinG: 0,
        startMaxG: 30000,
        maxVolumeG: 1,
        //
        startMinH: 0,
        startMaxH: 30000,
        maxVolumeH: 1,
        //
        startMinI: 0,
        startMaxI: 30000,
        maxVolumeI: 1,
        //
        startMinJ: 0,
        startMaxJ: 30000,
        maxVolumeJ: 1,
        //
        startMinK: 0,
        startMaxK: 30000,
        maxVolumeK: 1
      };

      masterClock();

      function masterClock() {
        setTimeout(function() {
          soundA(options, optionsA);
        }, 10); // these need to be called with delay so they don't use the other functions' paramaters
      }

      function soundA() {

        var soundFileName = 'audio/60.wav';
        fadeIn = 8000;
        fadeOut = 8000;

        console.log('soundFileName in A: ' + soundFileName);

        calculateStartDelay(optionsA.startMinA, optionsA.startMaxA);

        function calculateStartDelay(startMin, startMax) {
          startDelay = Math.floor(Math.random() * startMax) + startMin;
        }

        function calculatePlayDuration(playDurationMin, playDurationMax) {
          playDuration = Math.floor((Math.random() * playDurationMax) + playDurationMin);
        }

        function executePlayTools() {
          calculatePlayDuration(optionsA.playDurationMin, optionsA.playDurationMax);
          loop(options, playDuration, soundFileName, fadeIn, fadeOut);
          console.log('A: ////////////////////////////////// ');
          masterClock();
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
          if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointA) {
            maxVolume = optionsA.maxVolumeA;
            executePlayTools();
          } else if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointB) {
            maxVolume = optionsA.maxVolumeB;
            executePlayTools();
          } else if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointC) {
            maxVolume = optionsA.maxVolumeC;
            executePlayTools();
          } else if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointD) {
            maxVolume = optionsA.maxVolumeD;
            executePlayTools();
          } else if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointE) {
            maxVolume = optionsA.maxVolumeE;
            executePlayTools();
          } else if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointF) {
            maxVolume = optionsA.maxVolumeF;
            executePlayTools();
          } else if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointG) {
            maxVolume = optionsA.maxVolumeG;
            executePlayTools();
          } else if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointH) {
            maxVolume = optionsA.maxVolumeH;
            executePlayTools();
          } else if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointI) {
            maxVolume = optionsA.maxVolumeI;
            executePlayTools();
          } else if (probabilityValue < probabilityPointJ) {
            maxVolume = optionsA.maxVolumeJ;
            executePlayTools();
          } else {
            maxVolume = optionsA.maxVolumeK;
            console.log('Probability Else');
          }
          console.log('startDelay: ' + startDelay)
        }, startDelay);
      }
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // SHARED LOOP  ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    function loop(options, playDuration, soundFileName, fadeIn, fadeOut) {

      console.log('soundFileName in loop: ' + soundFileName);

      if (options.numberOfSounds < options.maxNumberOfSounds) { //Don't create more than the max number of sounds.

        var sound = getSound(soundFileName);
        var id2 = sound.play();

        logNumberOfSounds();

        sound.volume(0); // don't think I need this since it's declared above and in getSound(), but it stops blips?
        sound.fade(0, maxVolume, fadeIn, id2); // FADE IN

        setTimeout(function() {
          sound.fade(maxVolume, 0, fadeOut, id2); // FADE OUT
          options.numberOfSounds--;

          // Attempt to clean up the sound object
          setTimeout(function() {
            sound.stop();
            sound.unload();
          }, fadeOut + 1000);
        }, playDuration);
      }

    }

    // PLAYER FOR MAIN SOUND FUNCTION /////////////////////////////
    function getSound(soundFileName) {
      return new Howl({
        src: [soundFileName],
        autoplay: true,
        loop: true,
        volume: 0,
        fade: 0 // removes the blip
      });
    }
  </script>

  <script src="js/howler.core.js"></script>
  <script src="js/siriwave.js"></script>
  <script src="js/player.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the value of the variable correctly. Its value is defined inside the `soundA()` function, and then passed to the function `loop()` which doesn't have any way of knowing which variable is which.

There are two solutions to this problem. Either set pre-defined parameter names like so `function loop(options, options, playDuration, soundFileName, fadeIn, fadeOut){...}` then use those names in the function body, or you can go with the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) function object. The `arguments` object is an array-like object created with every function (with the exclusion of arrow functions) that contains all of its passed parameters, through which you can easily use the variables passed to it. See the example below:

```
loop(options, playDuration, soundFileName, fadeIn, fadeOut);

function loop() {
          console.log('soundFileName in loop: ' + arguments[2]); //The arguments object will contain all five parameters passed to the function call. 
}
```

Having said that, using an unknown number of parameters for functions is considered by some as bad practice as it could result in more errors and gotchas than with using pre-defined parameters. Nonetheless, the `arguments` object is there at your disposal and you get to structure your application however you want. Just put in mind that someone else might read the code and get confused along the lines.

Also, after solving this issue I was faced with another one that you're using a function in a separate script tag that comes before the declaration of the actual function, thus resulting in an `undefined` error.

Also, please mark this answer as the solution to help others passing by.

EDIT#1: As of ES6+ you can specify default parameter values in case you'd like to always keep the function behaving as expected even when values are not passed properly.

EDIT#2: As @nikolairiedel mentioned in the comments, the function `getSound()` is out of the declaration scope of that variable, thus being unable to get its value. You can set a parameter for that function and/or specify a default parameter value to make sure it works all the time as mentioned above in edit#1.

Comment: Thanks, @NabilTharwat for the thoughtful answer. I have changed the function definition for `loop` to include the expected parameters and have updated the code above with your suggestions. Nevertheless, I still get the "soundFileName is not defined" error. I will look more closely at your answer and see if I can better understand everything you said.

Comment: Adding `soundFileName` to `getSound()` as well as `loop()` solved the issue! As in `function getSound(soundFileName) {` @P.B.UDAY noticed this in a comment below. Please include in your answer. Thanks so much for your help! I'll look out for this in the future.

Comment: Oh, excuse me! I didn't notice that function at all as I was busy then. I've edited the answer to include those edits.

Answer (score 2):

Every function has its own scope and *variables declared within a function only exist within the scope of that function*.

In this case `soundFileName` is declared as a `var` within `soundA` so it only exists within the scope of `soundA`.

You are passing `soundFileName` as an argument to `loop`, and from there you are passing it to `getSound`, but your [function definitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Defining_functions) for `loop` and `getSound` do not include any named parameters.

You need to change the [function definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Defining_functions) for `loop` and `getSound` to include the expected parameters:

```
function loop(options, playDuration, soundFileName, fadeIn, fadeOut) {
  ...
  // soundFileName is now availabie in this scope
  ...
}


function getSound(soundFileName) {
  ...
  // soundFileName is now availabie in this scope
  ...
}
```

---

Note that within every function in `JavaScript` (excluding [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)) there is [a special `arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) that contains the arguments the function was called with, so since you passed `soundFileName` as the 3rd argument to `loop` the value passed will also be available within `loop` as `arguments[2]`, and since it was passed as the 1st argument to `getSound` it will also be available within `getSound` as `arguments[0]`.

Comment: Thanks, @brian-lives-outdoors I have changed the function definition for loop to include the expected parameters and have updated the code above. Nevertheless, I still get the "soundFileName is not defined" error. I will look more closelly at your answer and see if I can better understand everything you said.

Comment: @forestkelley I took a closer look and you will need to change the function definition for `getSound` as well.  You call `getSound(soundFileName);` within `loop` but `getSound` doesn't have any named parameters so `soundFileName` is undefined within its scope (same issue you fixed for `loop`).  Change the function definition for `getSound` to `function getSound(soundFileName) { ... }` and that should fix it.

Comment: @forestkelley I just noticed that @nikolairiedel pointed out `getSound` earlier and that it finished fixing the problem.  Glad to hear everything is working.  I've updated my answer to include modifying the function definition for `getSound`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try changing this

```
 function loop() {
```

to:

```
function loop(param1,param2.....){
```

In your case:

```
function loop(soundFileName,playDuration, ...){
```

Comment: It doesn't work, unfortunately. I have seen others suggest that parameters should be included in both the call and the function as you suggest. I'd be curious to know why that's importatn as it never seems to make a difference with my code. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: i'd say the same would hold true for the getSound() function. It should not make a difference if it is a nested function, and you are declaring a variable in the enclosing scope. But if you are declaring the variable to be used inside a function, in a different scope, in this case a different function scope, you should pass it as a parameter to the function :)

Comment: Yes! adding `soundFileName` to `getSound worked! As in `function getSound(soundFileName) {` Please include in your answer. Thanks so much for your help! I'll look out for this in the future.